# How do I make UITextview like Facebook comment view?

Tags: ios, uitextview, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to make UITextview like in the Facebook comment view. How can I do it without using any external libraries?

Here is example image:

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, set the appearance of your `UITextField` to *Alert* to get the black keyboard.
- Then, you only need two more views :

  - a black one for the background
  - a white one which will be the background of your text field, which you programmatically apply the following code to (don't forget to  `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` first):

    `view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;`

Answer (score 1):

i have get sample code for this - here it is [YIPopupTextView](https://github.com/inamiy/YIPopupTextView)

Answer (score 0):

What they do is use an image, that's it! They also probably expand the size of the UITextfield to make it fit the entire screen but yeah it's pretty easy. If you go into Interface Builder you can see a thing that says image. If you want to do this programmatically there is a value is textfield.background (A UIImage).

If you don't want to create an image you can create a custom UITextField subclass and use the -(void) drawInRect:(CGRect)rect function, and draw it with Quartz, and in interface builder set the UITextField class to your textfield.